# Reference needed: Category of modules over Frobenius algebra is a Frobenius category

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, modules, abelian-categories, algebras

Someone told me recently that the category of modules over a Frobenius algebra is a Frobenius category. Where can I find a reference for a proof of this?

Since the category of modules must be an abelian category (which is exact with respect to the class of short exact sequences) with enough projectives and enough injectives, this simply amounts to showing that the projectives and injectives over a Frobenius algebra coincide.